# 1366 (HY000): Incorrect decimal value: ''8.99'' for column 'price' at row 1

Tags: python, mysql, csv

```py
create_query = '''CREATE TABLE Sales(
order_num VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
order_type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
cust_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
cust_state VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
prod_category VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
prod_number VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
prod_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
quantity INT(255) NOT NULL,
price DEC(65) NOT NULL,
discount DEC(65) NOT NULL,
order_total DEC(65) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (order_num))'''

cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Sales")

cursor.execute(create_query)

with open('./red30.csv', 'r') as f:
    csv_data = csv.reader(f)
    for row in csv_data:
        row_tuple = tuple(row)
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Sales(order_num,order_type, cust_name, cust_state, prod_category, prod_number, prod_name, quantity, price, discount, order_total) VALUES("%s","%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")', row_tuple)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to allow decimal places in your column `price`:

```
price DEC(65, 2) NOT NULL,
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html

Comment: Also 65 digits of precision is probably excessive, unless you expect inflation to increase a lot!